# python "all" function making list empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and was learning its builtins but function [all()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all)
is not behaving as expected i don't know why.Here is my code

```
n=map(int,input().strip().split())
print(all([j>0 for j in n]))
print(list(n)) #this line returning empty list
```

Here are my inputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 -9
```

And my output:

```
False
```

Does function all changes the original map object(values)? but something like this is not mentioned in given function definition on the docs link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `all()` returns `True` if everything passed to it is `True`. You have -9 in your input so `j>0` for that is `False` so `all` returns `False`. What are you hoping to do to your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` returns a generator object which you exhausted in your `all` function. Therefore when you call `list` on `n`, since `n` is empty/exhausted, it returns an empty list.

To fix just make `n` a list in the first place.

```
n=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
print(all([j>0 for j in n]))
print(n)
```

Comment: Doubt cleared thanks!